# Unwanted blank line in verse environment

Tags: spacing, verse

I'm having a problem where lines which are *almost* long enough to cause the verse environment to break a line are creating an unwanted blank line. It seems as if the environment is breaking the line, but doesn't actually have anything to put on that line.

Here's a MWE which reproduces the problem:

```
\documentclass[ebook,10pt,twoside,openright,final]{memoir}

\usepackage{utopia}

\begin{document}

\begin{verse}
Ponder, daughter, distant marshy banks\\
where first was born the cold divorce\\
'twixt earthy bride and thundering, wrathful son.\\
The wedding broke, and strife poured out from wounds\\
unkindly torn. Already then I plotted\\
peace to make for fragile human hearts,\\
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

Rendered as:

[image: Rendering of the LaTeX fragment above.]

Upon simplifying the example, I see a warning message that I had missed before, namely the fact that the `utopia` package is now obsolete. Perhaps this is relevant?

Comment: That code works fine for me. Can you add a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?.

Comment: Me, too. The obvious completion to MWE produces code which does not have any problem.

Comment: @OSjerick I updated the question with a complete MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking the suggestion of commenters to post a complete MWE, I was able to solve the problem. With the simplified output, I finally noticed the following error message in the output spew:

```
Package utopia Warning: This package is to be regarded as obsolete.
(utopia)                See the PSNFSS documentation.
```

The [PSNFSS documentation](http://piotrkosoft.net/pub/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/required/psnfss/psnfss2e.pdf) recommends that you use the package `fourier` in place of `utopia`. And indeed replacing `\usepackage{utopia}` with `\usepackage{fourier}` causes the problem to go away.

Comment: Good! ;) Sometimes just making the MWE is part of the solution.