# Verse in memoir produces an unwanted extra empty line when the previous one is full

Tags: line-breaking, memoir, verse

I am having the same problem in `memoir` as [JSBձոգչ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1968/jsb%d5%b1%d5%b8%d5%a3%d5%b9). [This question had been posted before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277160/unwanted-blank-line-in-verse-environment), but unfortunately the solution proposed by the asker himself seemed to be a minor tweak and did not resolve the problem (besides, I cannot change the font to something else because I am using the standard CM). Let me quote this:

> I'm having a problem where lines which are almost long enough to cause the `verse` environment to break a line are creating an unwanted blank line. It seems as if the environment is breaking the line, but doesn’t actually have anything to put on that line.

Here is my MWE of the problem I got while typesetting a verse in Macedonian (`babel` has no Macedonian hyphenation rules, so I am using Russian ones):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
Tаа мозаична креација, Вавилон сака да го состави, \\*
секојдневно ја пишува светската историја "--- познавајќи исклучиво кинески, \\
работи на природен пергамент користејќи камен, \\
сликовно писмо со клинест примес \\*
и арапски акцент со јапонска мускулна моторика. 
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

[image: Wrong empty line]

This is likely to be a bug, so I do not want to change the `\textwidth` or other general parameters just for the sake of this occurrence (otherwise everything else will shift, which I do not want to happen).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm it shouldn't be needed but you can add `\nobreak` before the `\\` to avoid the double linebreak. You only need to add one, but I add one everywhere here to show it is safe to add even if the line is not exactly full.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
Tаа мозаична креација, Вавилон сака да го состави,\nobreak\\*
секојдневно ја пишува светската историја "--- познавајќи исклучиво кинески,\nobreak\\
работи на природен пергамент користејќи камен,\nobreak\\
сликовно писмо со клинест примес\nobreak\\*
и арапски акцент со јапонска мускулна моторика. 
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

---

I think this is  a bug in memoir which could be fixed using the definition as below

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@vslnumright}{%
  \nobreak%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  \hfill\rlap{%\kern\vrightskip\kern\rightmargin%
              \kern\memRTLvrightskip\kern\rightmargin%
              \vlvnumfont\getthelinenumber{poemline}{memfvsline}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{verse}
Tаа мозаична креација, Вавилон сака да го состави,\\*
секојдневно ја пишува светската историја "--- познавајќи исклучиво кинески,\\
работи на природен пергамент користејќи камен,\\
сликовно писмо со клинест примес\\*
и арапски акцент со јапонска мускулна моторика. 
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, David! You are a true TeX magician! By the way, what is the best way to report this bug to the developer? To write to the developer’s email address indicate in the readme on the CTAN page?

Comment: @AndreïKostyrka that's probably the official way but I did https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42923627#42923627 which will most likely also work:-)